# Trying to dynamically set the Icon based on a JSON string value

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a client config that is on a server in JSON format.

example JSON would be like { "icon" : "facebook" }

I have the widget below.

```
    class MySocialIcons extends StatelessWidget {

    MySocialIcons({this.icon, this.color});

    final String icon;
    final String color;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    switch(icon) {
      case 'facebook': {
        return Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.facebook, color: HexColor(color));
      }
      break;

      case 'twitter': {
        return Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.twitter, color: HexColor(color));
      }
      break;

      default: {
        return Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.home, color: HexColor(color));
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to not have to write 500 switch statements for 500 font awesome icons?  the format is

`FontAwesomeIcons.facebook`  where my string value "facebook" would append on the end of FontAwesomeIcons.   I am looking for a way to just write whatever I want in the string and it return the correct icon widget.

Comment: Here's a great use case for reflection. However that is not possible in flutter. There is a package called 'Reflectable' though, which does code generation (?). Maybe that's worth looking into.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways you can eliminate some of your code duplication.

1. By taking the switch out and moving it into it's own function so your build method has no duplication in it.

**Switch statement**

```
 IconData getIconForName(String iconName) {
      switch(iconName) {
        case 'facebook': {
        return FontAwesomeIcons.facebook;
        }
        break;

        case 'twitter': {
          return FontAwesomeIcons.twitter;
        }
        break;

        default: {
          return FontAwesomeIcons.home;
        }
      }
    }
```

**Build Function**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Icon(getIconForName(icon), color: HexColor(color));
}
```

or 2. **Create a Map**

```
Map<String, IconData> iconMapping = {
  'facebook' : FontAwesomeIcons.facebook,
  'twitter' : FontAwesomeIcons.twitter,
  'home' : FontAwesomeIcons.home
};
```

**Build Function**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Icon(iconMapping [icon], color: HexColor(color));
}
```

Comment: I am going to accept your answer because it does answer my question and is better code than what I was going to do, but I ended up just using a integer value of the icon and converting my JSON file from string based names to int based icon values, since it was less overall effort to convert 13 icons than support 500 strings in a map.

Comment: @Zuriel good choice. Better for long term maintenance as well.

Comment: it should be a better way. With this we end up having one case per icon. For these 3 it's ok. But I have a list with 50 of them

Comment: Wish flutter had feature like IconData.from("icon_name")

Answer (score 3):

Just follow the below steps to achieve.

1. Download the package [icons_helper]: https://pub.dev/packages/icons_helper from flutter packages
2. Just add below code wherever you want a dynamic icon using JSON.

   a) FontAwesome icon: getIconGuessFavorFA(name:"ICON_NAME")

   b) Material icon: getIconGuessFavorMaterial(name:"ICON_NAME")

Example:

```
ExpansionTile(
  leading:  Icon(getIconGuessFavorMaterial(name:root.menuIcon)),  //Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.dashcube),            
  key: PageStorageKey<MobileMenuList>(root),
  title: Text(root.menuName),
  children: root.children.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
)
```

*Note: If you face any error while complying like ('Error: Getter not found: 'haykal'.'). Just comment on the icon in 'icons_helper.dart'*

Comment: Should be the accepted answer +1

Answer (score 0):

I used the package reflectable and was able to reflect the existing modules fine.
Here are examples for colors and icons constants.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


@GlobalQuantifyCapability(r"Icons",constReflector)
@GlobalQuantifyCapability(r"Colors",constReflector)
import 'package:reflectable/reflectable.dart';
import 'adaptive_icons.reflectable.dart'; // Import generated code.


class ConstReflector extends Reflectable {
  const ConstReflector()
      : super(declarationsCapability,staticInvokeCapability);
}

const constReflector = ConstReflector();

dynamic colorFromName(String name) {
  ClassMirror m =  constReflector.reflectType(Colors);
  return m.invokeGetter(name);
}

dynamic iconFromName(String name) {
  ClassMirror m =  constReflector.reflectType(Icons);
  return m.invokeGetter(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this package

```
     awesome_icons: ^1.1.0

     import 'package:awesome_icons/awesome_icons.dart';

      Icon(
        fontAwesomeIcons['Icon_name'],
        size: 24.0,
      ),
```