# Saving Icon variable or color variable to firebase and using it

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, variables

I would like to save flutter variables to firebase as string `"Colors.black"` and use it in my code as  `color: document.data()['color']` however, I keep getting the following error  `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Color?'`

That's why I am asking how to save various variable types to firebase as strings and use them in flutter code as the types (Icon or Color).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string and a variable are two different language tokens. I don't think there's a way you could convert a string to use it as a variable name directly considering the fact that there's also a case needed to be handled when the string is not a valid name in your program.

However you would make sure that you only save the correct variable names in the database, the compiler/analyzer wouldn't understand that. So first, you need to add a middle abstract layer (for example, a proxy to an object in JS or just a function) and pattern match or switch-case the string to get the variable you need.

Here's how you can do it with a plain old function.

```dart
// Assuming you're working with Flutter
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' show Colors, Color;

Color getColorByName(String name) {
  switch (name) {
    case "black":
      return Colors.black;

    // default is for when the name is not recognized
    default:
      return Colors.transparent;
  }
}

void main() {
  const data = {"color": "black"};
  // --- ^ suppose data from db

  print(getColorByName(data["color"]));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works, however, I would like to make it more dynamic by using only the colors listed here:https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Colors-class.html and the flutter icons listed here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html

By using the official flutter Icons and colors I can ensure only "valid names" are stored in firebase.

How would this work with your code?

Comment: By looking at this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/d79295af24/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/colors.dart#L196, I don't think all these available color constants are listed. Not sure about the icons though. So you should use `dart:mirrors` or write your own analyzer or just pick these values out manually to list all these constants, and then use it in the switch of the example function. There's no other way, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for Icons here: [Dynamic Icons in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57869179/dynamic-icons-in-flutter)

This is it:
`Text('Add_Icon_String_Here', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons', color: Colors.white, fontSize: 50))`

All you have to do is change `Add_Icon_String_Here` to your icon string eg `add_ic_call`

Notes:

1. You can save the icon in firebase as a string like so: `add_ic_call` you don't need to add the `Icons.` prefix,
2. Make sure the icon exists, this way you can prevent errors. You could check here first: api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html